# Change first element in while loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a `while` loop that displays HTML.

However, I need a different element for the first iteration only.

How can I manage this? This is my code:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        ?>

        <div class="item" style="background-size:cover; background-image: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>); width: 100%; min-height: 300px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php comments_number( 'Pas de commentaires', '1 commentaire', '% commentaires' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
<?phph $flag = 1; ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($flag) { 

                   DO YOUR WORK;


                   $flag = 0;
                    }  ?>

   Rest of your code.
```

When the script will run for the first time it will find that the FLAG is true so you can do something different with the first loop. then the FLAG will become false. SO on next loop it wont get inside this 'if' which is used for first loop only

Answer (score 1):

Your complete code:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    $flag = 1;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if($flag == 1) { 

                   PUT YOUR CODE HERE;    

                   $flag = 0;
                    }

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        ?>

        <div class="item" style="background-size:cover; background-image: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>); width: 100%; min-height: 300px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php comments_number( 'Pas de commentaires', '1 commentaire', '% commentaires' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Thanks.